# When using EnumDropDownListFor in .Net MVC only the first selectable option is returned, regardless of which option tag is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I'm using an EnumDropDownList, but regardless of which option is selected, only the first selectable option ("0" because the enum values start from 1) is returned as input value. What have i missed?

Enum class:

```
public enum vehicleStatus
{
    Status1 = 1,
    Status2,
    Status3
}
```

Model for the razor page:

```
@model VehicleSearchFormViewModel
```

Code for the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Vehicles", FormMethod.Post))
```

Code for the EnumDropDownList:

```
<div class="input-field">
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.SearchParameters.vehicleStatus)
</div>
```

Search method in Controller. Say for instance that I choose "Status2" in the dropDownList. If I put a breakpoint when reaching the method during debug, the value for vehicleStatus in the carDetails object is still "0".

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(VehicleSearchFormViewModel carDetails)
    {

        IEnumerable<Vehicles> searchResults =_db.SearchResults(carDetails);

        carDetails.SearchResults = searchResults;

        return View(carDetails);
    }
```

My viewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TRAP.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TRAP.ViewModels
{
public class VehicleSearchFormViewModel
{
    private TrapDb db = new TrapDb();

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> vehicleHolder { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryOptions { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SubCategoryOptions { get; set; }

    public VehicleSearch SearchParameters { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Vehicles> SearchResults { get; set; }
}
}
```

VehicleSearch class (searchParameters):

```
using TRAP.Models;
namespace TRAP.ViewModels
{
public class VehicleSearch
{
    public int? vehicleId { get; set; }

    public int? diarieNumber { get; set; }

    public string vehicleHolder { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string subCategory { get; set; }

    public string registeredDateStart { get; set; }

    public string registeredDateEnd { get; set; }

    public bool? deregistration { get; set; }

    public vehicleStatus vehicleStatus { get; set; }
}
}
```

When inspecting the dropdown menu in a web browser:

```
<select id=”SearchParameters_vehicleStatus” name=”Searchparameters.vehicleStatus” data-val-required=”The vehicleStatus field is required.” data-val=”true”>
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Status1</option>
<option value="2">Status2</option>
<option value="3">Status3</option>
</select>
```

My Index GET

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var viewModel = new VehicleSearchFormViewModel()
            {
                SearchParameters = new VehicleSearch()
            };

            using (var db = new TrapDb())
            {
                var allOptionsList = new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "", Value = "" } };
                var vehicleHolder = 
                    allOptionsList.Union(
                        db.Vehicles
                            .Select(
                                x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.vehicleHolder, Text = x.vehicleHolder }))
                            .ToList();

                var categoryOptions = allOptionsList.Union(db.Vehicles.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Value = m, Text = m })).ToList(); //distinct/unique

                var subCategoryOptions = allOptionsList.Union(db.Vehicles.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Value = m.subCategory, Text = m.subCategory }).Distinct()).ToList();

                viewModel.vehicleHolder = vehicleHolder;
                viewModel.SubCategoryOptions = subCategoryOptions;
                viewModel.CategoryOptions = categoryOptions;
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Full view

```
@using TRAP.ViewModels
@model VehicleSearchFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datefieldFrom").datepicker();
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datefieldTo").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
}

<nav class="left-nav">
    <ul>
        <li>Systemkonfigurerare</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/arrow.png">@Html.ActionLink("Tillbaka till startsida", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/addDocument.png">Ansöka om ny fordonstyp</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/addDocument.png">Registrera ny fordonstyp</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/addDocument.png">Registrera ny sammansatt fordonstyp</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/addDocument.png">Registrera ny fordonsindivid</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/calender.png"> Fordonstyper med avvikelser </li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/calender.png">Antal godkännanden </li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/calender.png">Sök utgångna godkännanden </li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/calender.png">Statistik fordonstyper </li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/coins.png">Årlig avgift</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/coins.png">Årlig avgift(detalj)</li>
        <li><img class="navIcon" src="~/Content/images/key.png">Systemkonfiguration</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="vehicle-page-upper-body">
    <div class="body-title-div">
        <h3 class="body-title">Sök fordonsindivid</h3>
    </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Vehicles", FormMethod.Post))
    { 
     <div id="left-search-div-container">

        <div class="search-field-div">
            <label class="input-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchParameters.vehicleId)
            </label>
            <div class="input-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchParameters.vehicleId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="search-field-div">
            <label class="input-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchParameters.diarieNumber)
            </label>
            <div class="input-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SearchParameters.diarieNumber)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="search-field-div">
            <label class="input-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.vehicleHolder)
            </label>
            <div class="input-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("carDetails.SearchParameters.vehicleHolder", Model.vehicleHolder)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

          <div class="search-field-div">
              <label class="input-label">
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchParameters.Category)
              </label>
              <div class="input-field">
                  @Html.DropDownList("carDetails.SearchParameters.category", Model.CategoryOptions)
                   /
                  @Html.DropDownList("carDetails.SearchParameters.subCategory", Model.SubCategoryOptions)
              </div>
          </div> <br />

        <div class="search-field-div">
            <label class="input-label">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchParameters.registeredDateStart)

            </label>
            <div class="input-field">
                <input type="text" name="carDetails.SearchParameters.registeredDateStart" class="datefieldFrom" /> <img class="calenderIcon" src="~/Content/images/calender.png" /> - 
                <input type="text" name="carDetails.SearchParameters.registeredDateEnd" class="datefieldTo" /> <img class="calenderIcon" src="~/Content/images/calender.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

          <div class="search-field-div">
              <label class="input-label">
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchParameters.deregistration)
                  @Html.CheckBox("carDetails.SearchParameters.deregistration", Model.SearchParameters.deregistration)

              </label>

          </div><br /><br />

          <div class="search-field-div">
              <label class="input-label">
                  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SearchParameters.vehicleStatus)
              </label>
              <div class="input-field">
                  @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.SearchParameters.vehicleStatus)

              </div>
          </div>

        <div id="search-buttons">
            <input type="submit" value="Sök" />
            <input type="reset" value="Rensa" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="right-search-div-container">

    </div>
    }

</div>

<div class="vehicle-page-middle-body">
   <div class="body-titel-div">
       <h3 class="body-title">Sök fordonstyp</h3>
       <p id="underProgressText"><i>Kommer snart..</i></p>
   </div>

</div>

<div class="vehicle-page-lower-body">
    <div id="lower-body-checkbox">
        @Html.CheckBox("keepSearchResult") 
        @Html.DisplayName("Behåll sökresultat")
    </div>

    <div class="body-titel-div">
        <h4 class="lower-body-titles">Om fordonsregistret</h4>
    </div>

    <p class="lower-body-text">Transportstyrelsens register över järnvägsfordon är ett IT-verktyg som används för att registrera fordonstyper och godkända fordonsindivider.</p>
    <p class="lower-body-text">Registret ska vara tillgängligt för de anställda men till viss del även för extrema användare. Verksamhetsutövare kan ansöka om ett användarkonto, och få tillgång till valda delar av registret. Det är till exempel möjligt att få en förteckning på sina egna registrerade fordon och att påbörja en ansökan om godkännande av ny fordonstyp.</p>
    <p class="lower-body-text">Allmänheten ser, baserat på fordonsnummer, viss utvald data från registret via Transportstyrelsens webbplats. Registret innehåller uppgifter om de viktigaste egenskaperna hos fordonen både på fordonstyp- och fordonsindividnivå</p>

    <div class="body-titel-div">
        <h4 class="lower-body-titles">Användarmanual</h4>
    </div>
    <p class="lower-body-text">
        Överst till höger finns en användarmanual Ladda ner manual. Här finns tips om hur ni använder de olika funktionerna i registret.

    </p>


</div>
<hr id="bottom-hr">
```

Comment: Strange, I copied and pasted your code into a new project and it works like it should. Post your index GET action

Comment: Are you using the `EnumDropDownListFor()` method in MVC5.1+? (I cannot reproduce your issue)

Comment: @JB06 
I have now added my index GET

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, I am

Comment: I am still unable to recreate this issue. Add your full view code. Another (unrelated) thing I noticed is that you have an unused database variable in your view model. Maybe you should remove that.

Comment: @JB06 full view added. Thank you, I have removed the database variable now

Comment: @JB06 I redid it myself now in a new project and it worked just fine. Strange...

Comment: @JB06 So I tried to remove all the other inputs in the view except the enumDropDown too see if it would start working, which it did. I then added one input at a time and when I added this it started to fail again:
@Html.DropDownList("carDetails.SearchParameters.vehicleHolder", Model.vehicleHolder).

Any idea?

Comment: @MazW Your view model property that contains the SelectListItems and the property inside of SearchParameters has the same name, vehicleHolder. Try changing the name of the SelectListItems property to vehicleHolderOptions.

Sometimes if properties have the same names, the default model binder can't distinguish between the two.

Comment: @MazW Also, try using the DropDownListFor HTML helper.

Comment: @JB06 I got it to work again by first changing the name as you suggested and then with this: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SearchParameters.vehicleHolder,  Model.vehicleHolderOptions)
It all works as it should now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MazW Glad to help. I'm going to add this as an answer so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the EnumDropDownListFor is a side effect of the model binder not working correctly because a property in your view model and the SearchParameter class have the same name, vehicleHolder.

Change the view model property's name to vehicleHolderOptions and in your view, use @Html.DropDownListFor instead of @Html.DropDownList.